# LLVM Compiler Optimisation causing broken logic with boolean class members

Tags: c++, macos, optimization

We have a very basic type masking system that will run a simple XOR on memory. We hit a bug that only appeared in optimised builds when it was used on a boolean. I had initially dismissed it as "we shouldn't really be doing that kind of memory logic on a boolean type", but I wanted to look into it further to figure out exactly where it was going wrong.

After a bit of investigation, the circumstances under which this breaks seems a little odd to me. We seem to end up with a situation where a member function will not return the correct value, always returning true. However the underlying memory showing that the masking has worked as expected and it should really return the correct value.

This is our function that will XOR the memory (usually templated, forced to bool here to simplify things):

```
void Op(bool &v)
{
    uint8_t *val = (uint8_t *)&v;

    for (uint32_t i = 0u; i < sizeof(bool); ++i)
        *(val + i) ^= 0xFF;
}
```

So you can see it is making an assumption about a bool taking up a byte which is not safe, however, I have put in debugging output to show the actual data in memory in the full file [here](http://pastebin.com/428qKGAB).

Where this gets interesting/confusing is that the process of masking and unmasking seems to work in the following case regardless of optimisation settings:

```
bool Get()
{
    bool mangledBool = false;
    Op(mangledBool);

    bool v = mangledBool;
    Op(v);
    return v;
}
```

`Get()` will return `false`, which is correct.

However, if we use a class with a member variable:

```
class BoolMangle
{
public:

    BoolMangle()
    {
        m_MangledBool = false;
        Op(m_MangledBool);
    }

    bool Get()
    {
        bool v = m_MangledBool;
        Op(v);
        return v;
    }

    bool m_MangledBool; 
};
```

Like this:

```
BoolMangle test2;
bool ret = test2.Get();
```

`ret` will be `true` when using -O2, but `false` in debug.

There is a complete source file [available here](http://pastebin.com/428qKGAB) that should build and run in Xcode on OSX. It outputs the memory from the variables for the 2 different approaches, and the final booleans.

This is the output I am seeing:

```
>Op ( 0x00 ) 
<Op ( 0xff ) 
>Op ( 0xff ) 
<Op ( 0x00 ) 
mangledBool = 0xff, v = 0x00
bool test1 (False) = False (0x00)

>Op ( 0x00 ) 
<Op ( 0xff ) 
>Op ( 0xff ) 
<Op ( 0x00 ) 
m_MangledBool = 0xff, v = 0x00
BoolMangle test2 (False) = True (0x01)
```

It appears that although the call to Op has not been optimised away (we can get debug output from it), the compiler has assumed it will not affect the outcome of the Get member function, and hard codes a return value of true.

I would really appreciate it if anyone would be able to answer why this would be the case, and why it would only happen in the member function.

EDIT: To be clear, I am in no way suggesting that any of this is legal code, I am interested in how the compiler is optimising, and how it differs for these circumstances.

Comment: Uncommenting the suggested line doesn't change anything on my OSX El Capitan Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)... Worst if I change to  `printf(" v = %s %d\n", v ? "True" : "False",v);` I see `v = True 0`!!!!

Comment: `volatile` parameter will correct the problem.

Comment: About strict aliasing and your problem http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have already said, your program's behavior is odd because it has undefined behavior due to the aliasing violation that results in accessing `bool`s with illegal values.

There are a lot of factors in the optimization that could cause the observed behavior. For legal boolean values the following two conditional statements are equivalent:

```
if (boolean is bitwise equal to 1) {
  foo();
} else {
  bar();
}

if (boolean is bitwise equal to 0) {
  bar();
} else {
  foo();
}
```

Enabling optimization can cause the generated code to switch between these, or the optimizer can choose which to use in different contexts. The optimizer can even inline code, be able to compute the conditional at compile time, and entirely eliminate the actual test.

Since these conditionals are not necessarily equivalent for *illegal* boolean values you can get different behavior depending on the optimizer and all of the factors that cause the optimizer to choose between 'equivalent' code. In the case of inlining and eliminating the test, the final behavior may be different from what the hardware would have done without inlining.

And optimization isn't limited to just two ways to implement that test. Some others are:

```
if (boolean is bitwise equal to 1) { foo(); }
if (boolean is bitwise equal to 0) { bar(); }

if (boolean has least significant bit set) { foo(); } else { bar(); }
```

There's an infinite variety of 'equivalents' for the optimizer to choose among, with many different possible weird, logically impossible behaviors: executing both sides of an `if/else`, executing neither side, executing one side and then having later code act as if the other side were executed, etc.

---

> I am interested in how the compiler is optimising, and how it differs for these circumstances.

Lots of different factors go into how the optimizer picks what code to generate. Here's one example that causes one of your `Get()` functions to be optimized like the other:

```
static void escape(void *p) {
  asm volatile("" : : "g"(p) : "memory");
}

bool Get()
{
    bool mangledBool = false;
    Op(mangledBool);

    bool v = mangledBool;
    Op(v);
    escape(&mangledBool);
    return v;
}
```

---

Take a look at the runtime output of your program when using "UBsan", a detector for many kinds of undefined behavior:

```
prog.cc:29:14: runtime error: load of value 255, which is not a valid value for type 'bool'
prog.cc:33:12: runtime error: load of value 254, which is not a valid value for type 'bool'
prog.cc:48:18: runtime error: load of value 255, which is not a valid value for type 'bool'
prog.cc:53:16: runtime error: load of value 254, which is not a valid value for type 'bool'
```

[Live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/uSeKgNAtm0Jyg2BP)

UBsan is a useful tool for finding many kinds of undefined behavior.

---

> So you can see it is making an assumption about a bool taking up a byte which is not safe,

Actually that part is perfectly safe; `bool`s can't take up less than a byte because every `bool` object must have its own address and that address has to be convertible to a `char*`. An optimizer might able to play games with this, but never in a way that a legal program could tell.

Answer (score 1):

In an optimised build (-O2) and above, `-fstrict-aliasing` is enabled. You are falling foul of this because you are cheating the compiler by casting a `bool&` into an unrelated type.

Because of this, the optimiser is caching the value of the bool, unaware that it may change before the end of the function.

Moral of the story: don't rely on undefined behaviour - write legal programs.

Comment: Disabling strict-aliasing in xcode does not change the output. Also, in xcode, 'Enforce Strict aliasing' is enabled for debug builds too.

Comment: It doesn't seems to be an aliasing problem as replacing `int8_t` by `char` will not change the problem.

Comment: Specifically setting -fno-strict-aliasing doesn't change the output either, but I'm starting to wonder if LLVM ignores these settings.

Comment: interesting, but UB is UB. Attempting to reason "why" isn't going to get us anywhere :)

Comment: `uint8_t` is `unsigned char` in this implementation and the aliasing rules specifically allow you to access other types through `char` types. I don't believe this is an aliasing violation. However assigning a value through the `char` pointer and then reading that value from the bool may be an aliasing violation.

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not mandate a representation of `bool`. Generally, we can say that there is at least one bit pattern which represents `true` and one bit pattern that represents `false`. But we can't say which patterns those are, and we can't say how the other 254 bit patterns behave.

In particular, we can have bit patterns which are neither `true` nor `false`. It's Undefined how those behave, and what havoc they cause. They certainly don't need to follow nice boolean conventions such as `A and True = A`

If you follow strict aliasing rules and don't have other Undefined Behavior either, you won't run into these bitpatterns. However, you violate the strict aliasing rules as well. Sure, you can turn off the compiler enforcement of the aliasing rule, but that doesn't make the bitpattern suddenly legal.

Comment: To be specific the violation of strict aliasing in this code is after where the `bool`'s memory has been assigned to: the memory has had a `uint8_t` value written to it, and then that value is being read as though it were a `bool`. Reading a `bool` as a `uint8_t` is legal, but the otherway around is not.

Comment: Furthermore, the flag `-fno-strict-aliasing` only 'fixes' aliasing violations that have to do with assuming certain writes don't affect the value of certain other variables. Aliasing violations such as the one in this code which result in variables having illegal values or being trap representations are not fixed with `-fno-strict-aliasing`.

Answer (score 1):

Writing code whose correctness depends on the bit representation of `true` and `false` results in unspecified behavior (not undefined behavior). The compiler is free to not only chose any bit representation(s) for these literals but also to change the bit representation when performing [constant folding and propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) and other optimizations (this doesn't apply to conversions between integral types and the Boolean type. See 4.5, 4.7 and 4.12).

In this example code you provided, the argument passed to the second call to `Op` in this code:

```
bool Get()
{
    bool mangledBool = false;
    Op(mangledBool);

    bool v = mangledBool;
    Op(v);
    return v;
}
```

and the argument passed to the call to `Op` in this code:

```
bool Get()
{
    bool v = m_MangledBool;
    Op(v);
    return v;
}
```

may or may not be 0xFF. It could be 0x1 or any other value. XORing 0x1 with 0xFF doesn't result in the value you expect. In addition, even if these calls to `Op` produced the expected result, the binary value returned might be different from what you expect and it could be inconsistent across the code.

I suggest your try also this:

```
void Op(bool &v)
{
    bool *val = (bool *)&v;

    for (uint32_t i = 0u; i < sizeof(bool); ++i)
        *(val + i) ^= 0xFF;
}
```

and this:

```
void Op(bool &v)
{
    uint32_t *val = (uint32_t *)&v;

    for (uint32_t i = 0u; i < sizeof(bool); ++i)
        *(val + i) ^= 0x1;
}
```

and see what happens.

Comment: The undefined behavior happens when the aliasing rules are broken by reading a `uint8_t` value through a `bool` type. If you run the OP's code with UBsan it will produce runtime errors at the points where this occurs.

Comment: @bames53 Of course this is UB, but this is irrelevant to the unexpected behavior of this particular program. Therefore, saying that the program has UB and so it behaves that way is fundamentally wrong. The actual reason as I said above is because of the unspecified behavior. You could remove UB by using `bool *val = (bool *)&v;` and you would still have the unexpected behavior that the OP is puzzled with.

Comment: Actually changing `val` to be `bool` eliminates not just the undefined behavior but also the unspecified behavior you're talking about, because with that change the code is no longer depending on the bit representation of bools and is instead just doing well defined conversions between `int`s and `bool`s.

Comment: @bames53 No. If you perform that change, the result will be TRUE both times (it should be FALSE both times). Also this expression `*(val + i) ^= 0xFF;` is the one that causes unspecified behavior. This expression `(uint32_t *)&v;` causes only UB.

Comment: The result will be true both times, but that's expected because you've changed the definition of `Op()` to effectively be: `void Op(bool &v) { v = true; }`. If `val` is a `bool*` then the expression `*(val + i) ^= 0xFF;` is simply a complicated way assigning the bool `true`. If the result were `false` then _that_ would be unexpected behavior.

Comment: @bames53 I meant the result of `Get()` not `OP(bool&)`. By "result" I mean the output of the program provided by the OP.

Comment: Yes, since your change to `Op()` now always sets the bool to true, `Get()` now does the same thing. It's effectively `bool Get() { bool mangled = false; mangled = true; bool v = mangled; v = true; return v; }`. So if `Get()` returned false that would be very unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment of scrambled bools is illegal.
`bool v = m_MangledBool;` You have no guaranty, that m_MangledBool is `true` or `false`, and no proper value (or bit-pattern) you have assign to v (while such assignment is the only defined behavior of the statement here).
For example, as m_MangledBool is not false (0), v may be initialized as true (0x1). After scrambling it should be again not 0.

Comment: And it's not just assignment; any lvalue to rvalue conversion on that scrambled bool causes undefined behavior. E.g. printing `m_mangledBool` out or using it in a conditional.

Comment: After some thinking and research I think it is an indeterminate value. And in my opinion using a valid object with an indeterminate value should not results in undefined behavior. (The behavior should be unspecified) IMHO. (and llvm seems works this way).

Comment: The reason it's undefined is that when the `uint8_t` values is written that ends the lifetime of the `bool` and now there's a `uint8_t` living in its storage [n4140 §3.8 basic.life p1]. Reading that value through the `bool` then is UB based on both [§3.10 basic.lval p10] and [§4.1 conv.lval p1]. That's my interpretation, anyway.